# GestureOverlayView not recognizing multiple strokes

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition, gestures

I have a very simple but but complicated question.
Here i am creating english alphabates practising app for kids.
I am using GestureOverlayView in my app for recognizing drawing.

All works fine but what i want to do here is that kid can trace a letter in multiple stroke.

For that i used

```
android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
```

for supporting multiple strokes and,

```
android:fadeOffset="2000"
```

for putting timing between two strokes.

But when i try to trace a letter in multiple stroke , my listener not calling( just nothing happens ) and i could not recognizing the gesture.

So my question here is that how to enable multiple strokes drawing in gestures ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had this problem too and then realised that there are a few settings that have unnaturally high values in the Gesture Overlay View.

Try putting these in the xml markup (or code if you wish)

```
android:gestureStrokeLengthThreshold="1"
android:gestureStrokeAngleThreshold="0"
android:gestureStrokeSquarenessThreshold="0"
```